# How do i make a json merger based on non unique keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react native app with a calendar that use dates as keys in JSON.
So I want to add to the objects to the JSON file .

here is the basic JSON file I have

```js
[{"2021-03-22":[{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test2"}],"2021-03-23":[{"name":"test3"}]}]
```

I want to do is to add

```js
{"2021-03-23":[{"name":"test4"}]}
```

and the goal is

```js
[{"2021-03-22":[{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test2"}],"2021-03-23":[{"name":"test3"},{"name":"test4"}]}]
```

and if I add

```js
{"2021-03-24":[{"name":"test4"}]}
```

it will go

```js
[{"2021-03-22":[{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test2"}],"2021-03-23":[{"name":"test3"}],"2021-03-24":[{"name":"test4"}]}]
```

--sry if the code JSON bit wrong but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It looks like a booking app. There’re date-keyed slots, and unique person is added to one of the slot. If guy already in slot 23, and he add himself to slot 24, then need to remove him from slot 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get your logic. But I hope this code can help you to build your own logic.

```js
let arrayTest  = [{"2021-03-22":[{"name":"test2"},
                                 {"name":"test2"}],
                   "2021-03-23":[{"name":"test3"}]
                }]


const keyParam = "2021-03-23";

Object.entries(arrayTest[0]).forEach(([key]) => {
    if(key === keyParam){
        arrayTest[0][key].push({"name":"test4"})
    }
});

 console.log(arrayTest);
```